# Assigning the output of 'ps -a -u user -F` to a SHELL variable

Tags: bash, shell

I 'm trying to capture VNC sessions running. So I use as below

```
    STAT = `ps -a -u user -F | grep "Xvnc :" | grep -v grep`
```

If VNC session is running, the output of command "ps -a -u user -F" is multiple lines. Then STAT is assigned all the lines. I 'm just interested just ONLY ONE line, as all I wanted all the SESSION NUMBER s of VNC running for the "user" . I tried the command below, to use "@" as my delimiter (insteard of "\n" to parse STAT). It doesn't seem to work

```
    STAT = `ps -a -u user -F | grep "Xvnc :" | grep -v grep | tr -s "\n" "@"
```

All I need is to grab the VNC session number(s). Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please show a sample output of the first command, and the desired output from it.

Comment: By "Session numbers," you mean something like ":2" ":3" and the like? (X display numbers?)

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `ps` supports it, you would be better off reformatting its output to make it easier to parse. On my system I can do this:

```
$ ps -o command= -C Xvnc
Xvnc :1

$ ps_output="$(ps -o command= -C Xvnc)"

$ vnc_display="${ps_output#Xvnc :}"

$ echo $vnc_display
1
```

Of course this method has a number of limitations. It does not select a particular user, and will not work if you used other command-line options to `Xnc`, or if you have multiple sessions running. So instead, you might want to do something like this:

```
$ grep -z "^:" "/proc/$(pgrep -u user Xvnc)/cmdline"
:1
```

Set to a parameter with command substitution, and then potentially remove the colon if that's what you want. This still won't work if a single user is running multiple VNC sessions. You'll have to iterate over the results of `$(pgrep -u user Xvnc)` instead. If you don't care about nicely parsed output since a human is dealing with the results anyway, you could always just do this:

```
$ ps $(pgrep -u user Xvnc)
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3600 pts/2    S      0:00 Xvnc :2
 3606 pts/2    S      0:00 Xvnc :3
```

The way this works is by running the `pgrep` command, which will search for processes that meet specified criteria (in this case, running under user `user` and with the command name `Xvnc`). Here's what its output would look like:

```
$ pgrep -u user Xvnc 
3600
3606
```

Encosing this in `$(` and `)` engages the shell's *command substitution facility*. This takes the output of a command and substitutes it in as part of your command line. (Run `info "(bash)Command Substitution"`) for more information). When you run `ps $(pgrep -u user Xvnc)`, it causes the shell to interpret it as this:

```
$ ps 3600 3606
```

which will produce the same output. You can see exactly what Bash is doing if you use the `set -x` debug option:

```
$ set -x
$ ps $(pgrep -u user Xvnc)
++ pgrep -u user Xvnc
+ ps 3600 3606
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3600 pts/2    S      0:00 Xvnc :2
 3606 pts/2    S      0:00 Xvnc :3
```

Comment: *very* nice, that's going into my toolbox.

Comment: Awesome. Can I have some explanation abt "ps $(pgrep -u user Xvnc)

Comment: Sure, additional explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

To process a list of session numbers:

```
$ for snumber in $(ps -a -u USERNAME -F | grep -o -P '[X]vnc :\d+' | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }'); do echo Session ${snumber}; done
Session 2
Session 1
$
```

To have a list of session numbers in one variable:

```
LIST=$(ps -a -u USERNAME -F | grep -o -P '[X]vnc :\d+' | awk -F':' '{ print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's; $;;')
```

Comment: Great answer. Modified this a bit as I 'm interested only in session number say 8. Modified the above command as below -  ps -a -u cad -F | grep -o -P "Xvnc :\d+" | grep "Xvnc :8" - I get a error saying "grep No such file or directory and Xvnc No such file or direcotry

Comment: All grep does is "ouput" the part of the string that matches the pattern "Xvnc :\d+" => Xvnc followed by : followed by atleast a digit. What's the MISTAKE is piping it to a 'grep' to look for a particular "digit" from N number of Xvnc sessions ?

Comment: @Mike: It is not a mistake, but could be after your changes. I'd say read "man grep" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want X display numbers (e.g. :1, :2), you could try:

```
  STAT=`ps -a -u ${USER} -F | \
     perl -ne '$\=" ";if (/^.{64,}Xvnc.*?:([0-9]+)/){print $1}'
```

This might be a *little* safer under esoteric conditions, because it skips the first 64 columns of `ps` output before looking for `Xvnc`, and the regexp is complex enough that it can't match itself. This will load `$STAT` with a space-delimited list of X display ID's, e.g. "2 4 6" or similar, suitable for use in `for n in $STAT; do echo "$USER is on :$n"; done`

(broken-out:

```
   $\=" ";       # print a space after every print command
   if (/^        # start of line (matches the input line 
        .{64,}   # at least 64 characters
        Xvnc     # the bit you wanted
        .*?      # any other spaces or parameters that might be around
        :        # find a colon
        (\d+)    # find, and keep, at least one digit
        /x)      # (the /x only so I can put comments into the regex here)
   { print $1 }  # print the digits that we found in () group 1
```

and `perl -ne` puts an automatic `while(<>){}` loop in place to read the input)